# Discard form elements

Tags: forms

I would like to know if there is a way to simply not save elements from a form. I know that we can hide elements with `hide()`, or `#type = hidden/value`, etc., but I would like to remove then completely from the form saving process.

I'm building a lot of "partial" forms (small part from a big one) and every time that I want to build a small form, with 2 fields, Drupal processes 20 fields and I have to hide the others 18 fields. It doesn't make sense for me.
I'm sure that Drupal can handle this better than hide and I'm missing something.

Example:
Complete form: name, age, city, country, phone
Form #1: name, age
Form #2: city, country

I would like to build a form like the **#1** (with name and age only) and save it without loosing the data from city, country and phone BUT without hiding fields, valuing them nor with `#access = FALSE`.

Let me know if I'm still not clear enough. THANKS!!

Comment: How about conditionally using `unset` on form fields in a `hook_form_alter` function?

Comment: What about the [disabled](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#disabled) [attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp) for the fields?

Comment: Are you creating multi-steps form?

Comment: @develkar, with unset I lose the field value.

Comment: @enzipher, I can't disable any fields... for example, checkboxes are not able to be disabled.

Comment: @Sithu, no! normal form, one step.

Comment: @Fabio Sure you can disable checkboxes. Have a look at the [Form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7).